# Where does Transmission store logs for called scripts?

Tags: terminal, command-line, logs, torrent

[Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) has an option to run a shell script when a file finishes downloading. I'm wondering where to look for logs for it – it seems like it only executes half of my script but can't figure out where to look to figure out what's going wrong.

I looked in the Console.app at all the different log files and haven't found anything related to Transmission.

I understand it might not be a special app-specific place since it just executes a .sh file but I just wasn't able to find it.

Comment: What version of transmission are you running? What version of Mac OS X? I'll test and post the answer.

Comment: I suggest you rephrase your question to something like: "Why doesn't Transmission run my shell script to completion?". And please provide the shell script that is supposed to run and what makes you think it isn't run to completion.